# Real data in Ruby on Rails join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, join

In our RoR app, we have two core models and a join table:

```
class Workflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workflow_datafiles
  has_many :datafiles, :through => :workflow_datafiles

class Datafile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workflow_datafiles
  has_many :workflows, :through => :workflow_datafiles

class WorkflowDatafile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :datafile
  belongs_to :workflow
```

The join table has its own model code, and contains an actual data element that describes the nature of the relationship between a given workflow and datafile.  I've written code to import data from XML files, and I need to put some data into the join rows after I associate the imported files and workflows.  The problem is that, even though an unsaved workflow object has a datafiles array, and an unsaved datafile object has a workflows array, neither has a workflow_datafile array.  I think they show up after I save (I should verify this, I guess).

So, when I'm processing the XML file, instantiating workflow and datafile objects, and adding them to each other's collections, I don't have a good way to access their join objects.

I see two options:

1. I could save the workflow and datafile objects at this point to force Rails to write them and their join rows out to the database.  Presumably, this would populate the .workflow_datafiles arrays, or at least let me query and update the rows I need directly in the database.  The problem with this is that both of these objects are part of a larger XML structure, and right now the code does all of its validations once everything is loaded, then saves it all at once. This would short-circuit that logic, and leave open the possibility that I create workflows and/or datafiles (and join rows) whose larger projects aren't in the database.
2. I could put code at a higher level of the XML processing to check the loaded data for workflows that have datafiles associated with them after saving the whole thing, and do some extra processing on them at that point to populate the join table columns.  This is a little more of a structural change to my code, and revisits structures I've already saved for post-processing, but at least it doesn't risk creating orphaned rows in the tables.

I'm leaning toward option 2, but I'm really hoping that someone has a better option, or at least some wisdom about the situation as a whole.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, i.e. your join table is not getting populated; how are you building `workflow`, `datafile` and `workflow_datafile` from the xml.  I think the problem is there because with the correct relationship definition all records should be inserted correctly and your relationship is correct.

Comment: I *think* the issue is that Rails is storing the workflow_datafiles data internally, but not making it available to the program until I save something.  And really, since the workflows and datafiles don't have id values before saving, normally there wouldn't be much to put in a join row anyway.  It's just that in my case, I need to access the join row explicitly to store real data.